# Do password derived encryption keys need to be salted?

Tags: encryption, databases, salt

If I have a database where I store users' sensitive information, and encrypt that information, do I need to do something like PBKDF2(password,salt,10^5) for the encryption key as well as the hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a human password and want to process it into some format that "leaves traces", then you need to do it with a function that is resilient to brute force (e.g. PBKDF2). You thus need to do that when you hash the password to obtain a password verification token that you store; you also need to do that when you are turning the password into a key for symmetric encryption.

To make things clearer: if you turn password *P* into key *K* and then use *K* to encrypt some data *D* and store the encrypted result *E*, then an attacker, observing *E*, could "try passwords" by turning a potential password *P'* into key *K'* and then trying to decrypt *E* with *K'* and see if it yields some sensible data *D*. This is the *offline dictionary attack* situation, very similar to basic [password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

Strictly speaking, turning some data into a key is called *Key Derivation*, and "PBKDF" really means "Password-Based Key Derivation Function".

Comment: So...is that a "yes"? Because I understand that you need to use a key-derivation/slow-hashing function. My question is if I needed to salt the key.

Comment: Slowness and salts are two important elements of password hashing (and its brother password-based key derivation). If you need one then you need the other, and vice versa.